# Django creating a DateTimeField(auto_now_add) on a populated table

Tags: django, django-models, django-database, django-syncdb

I decided to add a `created = Models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)` field to a model which already has objects instantiated (without `created` field of course), and I saved them as `initial_data`

So now when I run `syncdb`, I get the error `app_model.created may not be NULL` since it's trying to load objects without that field.

So how do I fix this? I wish it automatically assigned the time when I call `syncdb` as `object.created`. Can I make that?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you run migrations?

Comment: For some reason I don't want to use migrations.. I stick with syncdb. Probably not very practical :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a default value instead of auto_now_add.

```
from django.utils.timezone import now

class Something(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=now, editable=False)
```

It also makes your data field timezone aware and uses UTC.

Answer (score 0):

After you add a new field to a model, you need to create and run migrations, by running:

```
>>> python manage.py makemigrations
>>> python manage.py migrate
```

In this case, when it try to create the new non-null field, it will ask you if you want to add create a default value in your model or if you want to define a value now, you can choose add a value right there in console. When prompt ask for the value, you can use `datetime` module, so you can write as value:

```
datetime.datetime.now()
```

Comment: -or use the timezone.now() isntead of datetime.datetime.now()